# How can I deal with a professor with very weird English?

Tags: etiquette, language

I have recently enrolled in an elective course from our degree program. There is something that sometimes annoys me, namely the English used by the professor.

He is not a native English speaker, but it is not about his accent or pronunciation. These are decent. The problem is that he keeps applying the grammar rules of his native language to English. Sometimes, things he said in lectures were **logically** (sometimes, mathematically) nonsensical to everyone. The meaning of what he said was not always what he intended to convey (from a mathematical perspective).

That is also the type of English that we will see in the final exam. I have seen some past exam papers, and there is an inconsistency between the written requirements (in English) and his proposed solutions (mathematical translation of the requirements).

Normally, it is not a big deal for me. However, I occasionally gave him some suggestions in a very polite way instead of accusing him of using incorrect grammar, so it will be easier for students to understand during the lectures (and also during the exam). He always responded with something like "**well, it is natural to use this in real life**" and suggested that I should familiarize myself with his English instead. It disappointed me.

I want to take the matter further in a polite way *(is it even a wise thing to do?)*. What should I do in this situation?

*PS: I feel bad for asking this question as I quite enjoy his lectures*

*Update: We have reached a temporary solution with the professor. We will try to learn his English (through past exams), but he will also need to explain his "terminology" in detail. During the exam, we can ask him questions if there is anything ambiguous. It is something that we have to deal with.*

Comment: Has he requested your feedback? And is his speech honestly incomprehensible, or just quirky? If ‘no’ to both, do not take the matter further.

Comment: Learning grammar is difficult. Some people even have issues with the grammar of their native language. I'm pretty sure I still make many mistakes with English grammar. I don't think you can expect him to improve easily and he might simply not have any time he could allocate to English lessons. Are his mistakes consistent? Then you could take the approach of trying to learn his grammar.

Comment: "I feel bad for asking this question" No need to feel bad about being unhappy with your professor's unclear style of communication.

Comment: >"I should familiarize myself with his English instead". You just reminded me of Mr. Brown (Mind Your Language) when he taught the Arab Sheikh how to understand Scottish Gaelic instead of teaching his Scottish chauffeur English.

Comment: It seems difficult to me to offer advice without an example of the sort of grammar that would make something logically nonsense. Language is often implicit among native speakers: that is, background information is needed to understand the logical meaning of almost every sentence in English. I certainly understand if you don't want to provide a specific example, but maybe you can construct a new one that follows the same pattern.

Comment: This method would have to be used judiciously, but if he states something using language that is confusing (and you think is due to his non-native English based grammar), ask a question where you state it back with correct grammar. E.g. "In that last statement did you mean X Y Z?". You might get a grumpy "Yes. That is what I said." and the best you'll be able to respond is "Ah, sorry, it wasn't clear to me, and it sounded like maybe you meant Z Y X. Thank you for the clarification." Won't help on exams, and probably won't lead to him realizing the confusion he's causing, but might help a bit.

Comment: Interestingly, there was a recent post on Linguistics.SE concerning [applying the grammar of one language to another](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/45481). According to the top answer on that post, this behavior is called *interference*.

Comment: Which country??

Comment: @BryanKrause I imagine it's probably more on word usage. Like, "There are upwards 5 potatoes in my shopping bag. Each potato is worth $1.00. How many more should I buy to get a bag of potatoes worth $10?"

Comment: @BryanKrause It is indeed too specific to include in my post, yet I cannot think of an equivalent example, but it involves "mathematical logic". There were some occasions when our solutions were significantly different from his just because he used phrases having totally different meaning from what he intended to say. That was why I complained. Otherwise, I would not.

Comment: I have had this problem with the supervisor on my Master's thesis.  They were from a German-speaking country and spoke extremely strange English, all I can say is that I feel your pain.  The only thing that helped is that I have studied German before so that I knew what they meant when they made strange verb choices, it might help if you know some of that person's native language, so you know what they mean when they try to speak English.

Comment: One time I had a Romanian linguistics professor who always said "Let's discuss about this." One day I wrote her a small note saying, "One says: 'Let's discuss X' or 'Let's have a discussion about X,' but not 'Let's discuss about X.' " The next day, early in the lesson, she said very pointedly, "Now let's *discuss* it. Yes, let's have a *discussion about* it." She then smiled, shook her head knowingly at how wrong it sounded to her, and went on asking us to "discuss about" things from then on. :/

Comment: Which course are you taking? If it's undergrad, there should be a book or online notes on the course that has clear definitions. You could maybe advise to your teacher to use a book or notes to prepare the classes or at least the definitions and problems so everything is clear.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Considering that

> He is not a native English speaker, but it is not about his accent or pronunciation. These are decent.

the problem is not with understanding his pronunciation, but that

> Sometimes, things he said in lectures were logically (sometimes, mathematically) nonsensical to everyone. The meaning of what he said was not always what he intended to convey (from a mathematical perspective).

So the information he conveys is confusing and hard to, conceptually, understand. Since you also mention that

> That is also the type of English that we will see in the final exam. I have seen some past exam papers, and there is an inconsistency between the written requirements (in English) and his proposed solutions (mathematical translation of the requirements).

it seems that the communication issues also happen in writing. Now, if the issue with wording in assignments (or even in class) **is recurrent and several students agree with your take on it**, then it might be worth letting the professor know that **you all are having a hard time understanding**, without telling him what to do. Simple questions by a few students during class such as "could you explain that again, I'm not quite following?" or "are we supposed to do X or Y in the assignment?" will help you all conceptually understand what he is trying to convey at the same time that no one ".. [gives] him some suggestions ..." and be perceived as nit-picking his phrasing.

Answer (score 19):

Academia is an international environment, so part of the skills you will learn is dealing with people who speak another language than you do. Remember that you are extremely privileged: you can speak your own native language and expect others to understand you. All you have to deal with is other people not speaking your own language perfectly. Most people around the world have to deal with speaking English as foreign language to other people who also speak English as a foreign language, and try to make sense of the resulting chaos...

So I would just treat this as an exercise of an important skill you will have to have in your later life, and be thankful that the trouble you have is a lot less than the trouble other people around the world have.

Comment: In academia, you can and should expect others to speak English the same way you expect them to be able to read and use the Internet. Your answer does not, in my opinion, apply. If they are hired to teach in an English-speaking environment, they are required to speak English on a level adequate to the setting.

Comment: Your answer assumes that the OP's first language is English. Based on the information we have, I'm not sure if that's truly a valid assumption.

Comment: First year students complain they can't understand an Indian instructor's odd grammar. 3rd years have forgotten it was ever a problem and feel sorry for classmates who have never had an Indian instructor.

Comment: Odd grammar is one thing, and we should just live with it, but when mathematical precision is important the professor must be able to speak with precision.

Comment: Absolutely terrible answer. Clear communication is of great importance in a teaching environment, *especially* for mathematics.

Comment: I've witnessed this problem in mathematics before. It's not necessarily the math part, because you can write language-neutral equations down and get by with a few simple words (integrate, solve). The issue happens when they're trying to explain, say, physics behind the equations, or in the OP's case word problems. They can be successful in 90% of the teaching, but it falls apart in a critical 10%.

Comment: Being able to understand weird English is a skill, but the classroom is not the place to learn it, and a maths examination is not the place to test it. It is OK to not be able 
 to understand a talk at a conference, but not losing points in a test because a question was unclear.

Comment: This might be correct if you're answering the question in the title without looking at the details in the question body. But in the question body OP explains that it's not just accent or pronunciation, but about the precision of the meaning where precision is required, such as in mathematical exam.

Comment: @user253751 The instructor is probably speaking in the most common mathematically precise way, but the OP just doesn't know that. Even if they somehow know something is being said in a different way, that's a thing in math -- multiple terms for something, or even terms which can mean different things depending on context.

Answer (score 13):

1. Find support. Surely you are not the only student in your class with this problem. A request coming from many students has more leverage than one from a single person.
2. Make practical suggestions. For instance, suggest that he gets the final tests reviewed by a colleague for grammar before giving it to you.
3. Be polite. Phrase it as something like "Sometimes we have a hard time understanding the requirements", not "your English is weird". And, since you enjoy his lectures, start with a positive word.
4. If this second attempt fails, escalate the matter: get student union reps involved if you can, and speak to the head of studies.

Comment: All good points. However, #2 really shouldn't be necessary for a student to suggest. All exams should be subject to mandatory review before being taken. The main point of this is to catch technical errors, but it will also flag language issues.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime A review is not mandatory everywhere. And, even if there was one, it certainly was not effective in the past finals, so the process needs adjusting. The reviewer could be someone with an even worse command of English, or may have chosen not to focus on the grammar.

Comment: #1 is a good advice. I have not tried it as I normally talk to him privately.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, evidently it isn't mandatory everywhere - I was simply saying that it should be, as a matter of good practice. This was not meant as a criticism of your good answer, but of the institution in question.

Comment: Actually, I think #2 is excellent advice if you can make it happen.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Just curious, where are exams subject to mandatory review?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- it has been the case in universities I have worked at in the UK. I got the impression it was completely standard here.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Good to know.

Answer (score 6):

Like Federico Poloni [wrote in their answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/191157/38554), getting more students behind the cause will make it much stronger.

You have attempted to improve their lectures, but failed.  Speaking correctly is very hard since you have think about the subject matter and language at the same time.  They are not willing to make that effort.

Give up on that and concentrate on what is important:

### The Exam

The exam should be clear, unambiguous and correct.

If you have examples from previous exams that have failed any of these goals, that is where you should take the fight.  Be very concrete: "This sentence states X, but according to the suggested solution, you actually meant Y."

Make clear that students can actual fail because of the professors incorrect language.

Writing correctly is easier than speaking, since they can first think about the content and then go over a second time and look at the language.

You should suggest that they consult a native speaker to help them.

The exam is very important and should be worth the extra effort.

I am afraid you might have to take this fight twice.  First before the exam.  Then, when they haven't listened, repeat the fight so that people don't get bad grades because they misunderstood the questions.

After all that, warn the next year students they might have to repeat the fight.

Answer (score 4):

> I occasionally gave him some suggestions in a very polite way

So you have already tried offering him unsolicited advice...

> He always responsed with something like "well, it is nature to use this in real life" and suggested me to familiarize myself with his English instead

and he responded poorly.

> It disappointed me.

Yes, this is disappointing; you would expect that anyone speaking a foreign language would be pleased to get feedback from native speakers. Still, it is not really your role to provide this feedback, and he has made it clear that he is not open to receiving it. So, you should not broach the subject again unless you are invited to (e.g., in an end-of-course evaluation).

Comment: Although the feedback was unasked for, since "... some past exam papers, and there is an inconsistency between the written requirements (in English) and his proposed solutions (mathematical translation of the requirements)" the communication issue can and will affect the grades, and affect the overall quality of the class too. If the question was "instructor uses unconventional and inconsistent notation that stops us from correctly comprehending lectures and solving assignments" would you still say that unsolicited feedback from students should be avoided?

Comment: Yes, actually. It sounds like OP has already tried offering feedback more than once with negative results.  In really serious cases, you could try to insist, or escalate the issue, but that does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: I agree with the gist of your answer (do not broach the subject again). But I don't think that we can know from the question that the OP is a native speaker. If not, it would be one learner offering unsolicited advice to another learner. That's much more sensitive and potentially face-threatening than an interaction between a native speaker and a learner.

Comment: @Schmuddi OP's profile says they are from Adelaide, an English-speaking city, but the language of OP's original post makes me wonder whether English is perhaps OP's 2nd, 3rd, etc. language, e.g. "using wrong grammars" and "He always responsed" and "suggested me to"